# React-Redux: How to make sure an action is dispatched first before a PUT request is made

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following action creators:

menu.actions.js:

```
import { apiUrl, apiConfig } from '../../util/api';
import { INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK } from './menu.types';

export const decreaseCategoryRank = (category, categoryClicked) => dispatch => {
    console.log("Printing the category");
    console.log(category.name);
    console.log(category.rank);
    dispatch({ type: DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, category, categoryClicked })
    fetch(`${apiUrl}/category/${category._id}`, {
        ...apiConfig(),
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(category),
    });
}

export const increaseCategoryRank = (category, categoryClicked) => dispatch => {
    console.log("Printing the category");
    console.log(category.name);
    console.log(category.rank);
    dispatch({ type: INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, category, categoryClicked })
    fetch(`${apiUrl}/category/${category._id}`, {
        ...apiConfig(),
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(category),
    });
}
```

menu.reducer.js:

```
import { GET_MENU, INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK } from './menu.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = []


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MENU:
            return [ ...action.payload ];

        case INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {

            if(action.categoryClicked === false) {
                return state;
            }

            const menuArray = [...state];

            var index = menuArray.map(category => category._id).indexOf(action.category._id);

            if(index === 0) {
                return state;
            } else {
                const temp = menuArray[index];
                menuArray[index] = menuArray[index - 1];
                menuArray[index - 1] = temp;

                //reassign the ranks.

                var newrank = 0;

                menuArray.forEach(category => {
                     category.rank = newrank++;
                });

                return menuArray;
            }

        }
        case DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {

            if(action.categoryClicked === false) {
                return state;
            }

            const menuArray = [...state];

            console.log(menuArray);

            var index = menuArray.map(category => category._id).indexOf(action.category._id);

            if(index === menuArray.length - 1) {
                return state;
            } else {
                const temp = menuArray[index];
                menuArray[index] = menuArray[index + 1];
                menuArray[index + 1] = temp;


                var newrank = 0;

                menuArray.forEach(category => {
                    category.rank = newrank++;
                });

                return menuArray;
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

category-arrows.component.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { increaseCategoryRank, decreaseCategoryRank } from '../../redux/menu/menu.actions';
import './category-arrows.styles.scss';

class CategoryArrows extends Component {

    render() {

        const { category } = this.props;
        const categoryClicked = true;

        return (
            <div className="arrows-container">
                <div className="up-arrow" onClick={
                    () => {
                        this.props.increaseCategoryRank(category, categoryClicked)

                        this.props.menu.map(menuCategory => menuCategory._id !== category._id ? this.props.increaseCategoryRank(menuCategory, !categoryClicked) : null)

                }}></div>
                <div className="category-rank">
                    <p>{category.rank}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="down-arrow" onClick={
                    () => {
                        this.props.decreaseCategoryRank(category, categoryClicked)

                        this.props.menu.map(menuCategory => menuCategory._id !== category._id ? this.props.decreaseCategoryRank(menuCategory, !categoryClicked) : null)

                }}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    menu: state.menu
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { increaseCategoryRank, decreaseCategoryRank } )(CategoryArrows);
```

In my each of my action creators `increaseCategoryRank` and `decreaseCategoryRank`, I am dispatching an action and also making a PUT request through fetch, sending information about the category object to a server. My actions modify the rank of the category objects that are in the state.

However, in my code the PUT request is being sent before the action is being fully dispatched and the state is updated with the updated category ranks. As a result, the original category rank is being sent to the server. In addition, the `category` parameter passed to the action creator has the original rank value (since the action hasn't been dispatched yet).

I would like to have the action dispatched before the PUT request is made, so that I can send the updated rank of a category. However, I am not sure how to ensure that the action is completed and the state updated before making the PUT request.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: you are dispatching the action before the fetch request. Which will run before the PUT request.

Comment: However, the category object that is passed as a parameter to the action creator is the original category object that has not been modified. The category parameter is not updated/changed after the action has been dispatched within the action creator. How can I send the updated category to the PUT request?

Comment: what is the structure of your category object?